# Oracle 12c Import LRM error

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-migration, oracle12c, datapump

I have 2 different Oracle servers. And I will do migration from 11g to 12c. I am doing prova now. These 2 servers has a network mapped connection on folder.

I got full export from 11g to this shared folder successfully but when I trying to import I am getting below error. What to do and how to fix this issue?

> LRM-00109: could not open parameter file '/Backup/impdp_full_parfile.par'
>   LRM-00113: error when processing file '/Backup/impdp_full_parfile.par'

Comment: SO is for programming questions.  Try here instead - http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: sorry everyone. I fixed with file permissions. Notice for someone who will do this operation bw to servers by shared network connection. You should check file permissions.